# Предупреждение компилятора при передаче указателя в функцию потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, concurrency

Есть метод класса в котором создаю поток для другого метода этого класса:

```
void Core::Execute()
{
    ...
    InData it;
    ...
    thread tMain(&Core::ExMain,this,ref(p1),ref(p2),ref(p2),ref(p3),&it);
    ...
}

void Core::ExMain(const int &params1, int &params2, int &params3, bool &params4, InData *cit)
{
    ...
    for (vector<InData>::iterator it=vectData.begin(); it != vectData.end(); ++it)
    {
        cit = &(*it);
        ...
    }
}
```

В качестве одного из параметров передаю указатель на структуру it, в потоке меняю значение этого указателя на элемент массива

```
cit = &(*it);
```

но компилятор выдает предупреждение

```
C:\Project\JFStat\Core.cpp||In member function 'void Core::ExMain(const int&, int&, int&, bool&, InData*)':|
C:\Project\JFStat\Core.cpp|188|warning: parameter 'cit' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]|
```

как устранить это предупреждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы меняете указатель `cit`. Если бы Вы меняли значение, на которое указывает `cit`, тогда компилятор бы не стал ругаться. Но Вы просто присваиваете новый указатель. Скорее всего Вы хотели сделать что-то другое. Например вот это: `*cit = *it;`

Comment: нет, если бы я хотел менять значение я бы передал it в поток по ссылке как и все остальные параметры. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что поменять значение затратнее, чем сменить адрес на тот,где будет находится новое значение

Comment: @xttz, тогда передавайте указатель по ссылке:`InData *&cit`

Answer (score 0):

Предупреждение говорит что параметер `cit` присваивается но читается, то есть компилятор намекает что это бессмысленное действие. Следовательно если вы хотите избавиться от этого предупреждения вам нужно либо ничего не присваивать `cit`, либо как-то его читать/использовать.

Судя по коду: либо вы хотите вернуть указатель на один из элементов вектора, но неправильно объявили параметер для этого; либо используете параметр как локальную переменную, чего делать не стоит - лучше использовать отдельную локальную переменную.